# Unable to send files to thridparty server using php Curl

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, php-curl, php-5.4

I have tried below code, since our PHP version is little bit older 5.4.16, so this code is not working with that version, also new CurlFile($_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["upfile"]["type"], $_FILES["upfile"]["name"]), not working with php 5.4.16. any help is appreciated

```
$post = "@" . $_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"]
    . ";type=" . $_FILES["upfile"]["type"]
    . ";filename=" . basename($_FILES["upfile"]["name"]);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($post);
    echo "</pre>";

    $conn = curl_init('//third party url');

// send a file
    curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt(
        $conn,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        array(
            'file'        => '@' . realpath($_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"]),
        )
    );

// output the response
    curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


// close the session

    $result      = curl_exec($conn);
    $header_info = curl_getinfo($conn, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($conn, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header      = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
    $body        = substr($result, $header_size);
    curl_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

`'@' . realpath($_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"])`

What is the @ sign for? For preventing errors? It won´t. It will append the at sign at the beginning of your filepath, which leads to the problem, that the file is not found. IF you want to prevent errors, you have to just do `@realpath(...)`, but its discouraged to use this operator.

Removing it should fix your problem.

---

As Ingus mentioned, your Post data looks odd as well, you should not build the query string by yourself, instead use `http_build_query`, which is an inbuilt function from PHP.

Use it like a so:

`$post = http_build_query($_POST);`

Also by "not working", what do you mean exactly. What error are you receiving?

Comment: Whole $post line looks ood

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt   I am not receiving any errors, also the code that I have been refered from a blog https://rahulja.in/posts/send-files-using-curl-in-php-54 also I am not sure in php 5.4 how it can be done.

Comment: @Ingus The post line I am not using it, forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** try with this code:
If this still does not work try to check if file is there. ..

```
$url = '//third party url';
$post = array('file'=> '@'.realpath($_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"]));

$conn = curl_init();

curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //probably can remove
//curl_setopt( $conn, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); //if still not working try to uncomment this

$result = curl_exec($conn);
$header      = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
$body        = substr($result, $header_size); 

curl_close($conn);
```

Here is example of how i do it:
My file in this example comes from database as blob.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, type, size, content FROM my_files WHERE id='".intval($id)."'");

list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$name=html_entity_decode($name, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');


file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/temporarylocation/'.$name, $content);

$file_name_with_full_path = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/temporarylocation/'.$name);
$post = array('file'=> '@'.$file_name_with_full_path);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.":".$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$resu = json_decode($response, TRUE);
```

I hope this code helps you! Remember this is not ready to go code. Just an example. ..

Here are CURL manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: I have working code with PHP version 7.2 but the same code is not working with 5.4 version. but that won't solve the issue.

Comment: @Naveenbos add `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` on top of your file let us know what error it returns

Comment: I have added that too in the file, unfortunately it is not returning anything.

Comment: @Naveenbos also is curl installed on that device?

Comment: Yes The curl is installed, cURL support  enabled
cURL Information  7.29.0

Comment: Try to add `curl_setopt( $conn, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);` and see if that helps

Comment: @Naveenbos try with code i just posted in my answer

Comment: Call to undefined function curl_file_create() and also when I use new CURLFile PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CURLFile' not found